I am creating a plugin and getting a PlaceholderAPI error in Minecraft
Version 1.20.I am creating a plugin and getting a PlaceholderAPI error in Minecraft. The console gives me this error:
[18:02:29] [Server thread/ERROR]: Error occurred while enabling WarpManager v1.0 (Is it up to date?)
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "me.clip.placeholderapi.PlaceholderAPIPlugin.getLocalExpansionManager()" because the return value of "me.clip.placeholderapi.expansion.PlaceholderExpansion.getPlaceholderAPI()" is null

d!
I tried searching on the internet but without results. The error tells me that I haven't registered PlaceholderAPI, but I have.
Here is my WarpManager class:
@Override
public void onEnable() {
    instance = this;
    if (!setupEconomy()) {
        getLogger().info("Vault non trovato o non caricato correttamente.");
        getServer().getPluginManager().disablePlugin(this);
        return;
    }
    saveDefaultConfig();
    setupDatabase();
    if (Bukkit.getPluginManager().isPluginEnabled("PlaceholderAPI")) {
        placeholderExpansion = new WarpPlaceholderExpansion(this);
        placeholderExpansion.register();

        getLogger().info("PlaceholderAPI trovato e l'espansione è stata registrata.");
    } else {
        getLogger().warning("PlaceholderAPI non è disponibile. L'espansione non sarà registrata.");
    }
    getCommand("warps").setExecutor(new WarpsCommand(placeholderExpansion));
}

And here is my WarpPlaceholderExpansion class:
public class WarpPlaceholderExpansion extends PlaceholderExpansion {
    private final WarpManager plugin;
    private String warpName;
    private String warpState;
    private String warpOwner;
    private String warpPrice;

    public WarpPlaceholderExpansion(WarpManager plugin) {
        this.plugin = plugin;
    }

    @Override
    public String getIdentifier() {
        return "warp";
    }

    @Override
    public String getAuthor() {
        return plugin.getDescription().getAuthors().toString();
    }

    @Override
    public String getVersion() {
        return plugin.getDescription().getVersion();
    }

    public void setWarpData(String name, String state, String owner, String price) {
        this.warpName = name;
        this.warpState = state;
        this.warpOwner = owner;
        this.warpPrice = price;
    }

    @Override
    public String onPlaceholderRequest(Player player, String identifier) {
        if (warpName == null || warpState == null || warpOwner == null || warpPrice == null) {
            return "";
        }
        switch (identifier) {
            case "name":
                return warpName;
            case "state":
                return warpState;
            case "owner":
                return warpOwner;
            case "price":
                return warpPrice;
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }
}

The error tells me that I haven't registered PlaceholderAPI, but I have.
I tried searching on the internet but without results.

I suggest that you [edit] your question and post the entire stack trace of the NulPointerException that you are getting.

Have you included PlaceholderAPI in your dependencies?  If so, have you doubled checked in console that placeholder api actually starts up before your plugin?
